# JavaScript Understanding the need of event delegation

Tags: javascript

I read in one of the articles on the web this sentence:

> Adding event handlers to each of the 1000 cells would be a major
>   performance problem and, potentially, a source of browser-crashing
>   memory leaks.

But I don't understand it. If for example, I am doing something like this:

```
const handler = e => // do something

document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(td => {
   td.addEventListener("click", handler);
});
```

I **don't** create 1000 functions, they all use the same reference, so what I am missing? What is the problem?

Comment: If I understand, you're worry about memory leaks. The think is that everytime you click one `td` will execute that handler, per click

Comment: because you need to bind 1000 events, that is not free. (and in your example, you are binding one event)

Comment: Please link the article you were reading to cite the quotation and that we get some context.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't create 1000 functions, they all use the same reference, so what I am missing?

You would still create 1000 function references in the 1000 DOM nodes. This might not seem significant, but the table could grow…

Of course, you are basically right, if you don't create 1000 closures there won't be as many problems. However, do you really have 1000 buttons that all do the same? With closures, it's easy to let them do marginally different things; with only one function you would need to make it dynamically depend on the cell that was clicked (the event target). And when you're doing that already, you could just go ahead and use only a single function reference and event delegation…

Comment: "You would still create 1000 function references", can you explain this more, please? for my understanding all point of reference is that you have one reference.

Comment: If you add the same event handler to 1000 cells, each of the cells has its own reference to the handler function. Think of binding the event using `.onclick` - that would create 1000 properties.

Answer (score 5):

The way event delegation works is that you add an event listener in a parent element. When the parent triggers the event, you get a reference of the actual element that triggered the event and then check if that is the element you want to listen to
Maybe a code would help you understand it better

```
// Listen for the event on the parent...
document.getElementById("event-table").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // '.target' will now give us our actual clicked element
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "td") {
        // Wooho, a '<td>' node was clicked
        console.log("We have our click event delegated!");
    }
});
```

The way it helps is that now, instead of adding a eventListner on each element I can simply attach it to a parent and then check for it's child.

The real use of this functionality is when you want to attach events on some dynamically created elements. Say a row in your table is added dynamically after a database call. In such case, you would have to reattach a event listener to the new node if you're going the route of attaching the event to each node. But if you're using the delegation approach, as the event is attached to the parent, the newly created child node automatically becomes a part of the event

It can prove to degrade performance if you attach it to a parent that has many child's, which don't actually are the intended nodes for the event. For eg, if you attach the body node itself and then delegate to the 'td' tags inside it ! In theory it would work for sure but would potentially slow things down.

Comment: As @epascarello says You did not explain to the OP why it is bad to bind 1000 events. You explained bubbling.

Comment: @undefined, hope that answers your question

Comment: @MayankRaj Good point about dynamically created elements.  +1

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, events will bubble up the DOM chain.  When you click on `td`, any event handler on `td` will fire, and **also** on `tr` and on `table`, etc., all the way up the chain.

The article is telling you to register the event on `table` (for example) instead of each `td` element.

> I don't create 1000 functions, they all use the same reference, so
>   what I am missing? What is the problem?

You are not creating 1000 *functions* but you are registering 1000 *event handlers*, which is what the article is advising against. Register one event handler on some parent element, like `table`, instead.

Here is a [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yugkhubx/) on how to register **one** event handler for 1000 table cells.

Comment: You do not answer my question. Read it again, please.

Comment: You did not explain to the OP why it is bad to bind 1000 events. You explained bubbling.

Comment: @undefined, I've made my answer more explicit.

Comment: I've also added a jsFiddle example demonstrating how to add an event listener on only one parent element.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe an analogy will help you better understand it. Say you have a company where customers call you and you send them something.

- Attaching a unique event handler to each cell would like having 1000 phone lines, one for each customer and having to hire 1000 employees to man each phone waiting for orders.
- Attaching a single event handler to all of the cells is like still having 1000 phone lines, one for each customer but monitored by a single employee who has to figure out which customer's line is ringing and where to send the stuff. You no longer need 1000 employees but you still have 1000 phone lines.
- Using event delegation is like having a single phone line that all your customers call and a single employee who know where to send their stuff based on the caller id.

Using a single phone line makes your employee much more efficient.